# OCaml and dune : Integrate small libraries in a larger library

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

I am developing a big library with dune. Let us call this library `L`.

To avoid creating a big mess, the dune project has many smaller libraries : `A`, `B`, `C`, ...
These libraries depend on each other.

I would like the users to be able to `opam install L`, and then access to the different smaller libraries as `L.A`, `L.B`, *etc*.

What is the proper way to do this?

*Edit following the comment of @glennsl*:

Here is the filesystem tree:

```
l/
l/dune-project
l/a            <- This directory contains library A
l/a/dune
l/b            <- This directory contains library B
l/b/dune
```

in `l/a/dune` :

```
(library
 (name a)
 (public_name l.a))
```

in `l/b/dune` :

```
(library
 (name b)
 (public_name l.b)
 (libraries a))
```

in `l/a/dune-project` :

```
(name l)
```

I can't find how to expose `A` and `B` as modules of `L`.

Comment: Does it not work to just expose the `A`, `B` and `C` modules from `L`?

Comment: @glennsl My question was not precise. Sorry. I edited it to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there's some configuration setting that interferes, this should just be a matter of exporting the modules of the other libraries as module aliases:

```
(* L.ml (and L.mli) *)

module A = A
module B = B
module C = C

(* ... *)
```

This is in fact what `dune` does automatically to namespace library modules. And if you don't already have an explicit main module for `L`, you will have to manually add the module aliases that would have been automatically generated as well.

Comment: It works! I was looking in the stanzas... Did not see this obvious solution. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're aware that `dune` works like this it's definitely not obvious, no. There are a few hints in the documentation though, mainly in the introductory description of the [`library`](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#library) stanza and its `wrapped` field.